# Почему в драйвере функция вызывается без указания параметров?

Tags: c++, c, драйвер, kernel

```
VOID DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT driver) {
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(driver);
printf("-- unloading\n");

for (DWORD i = 0; i < SWAPS.Length; ++i) {
    PSWAP s = (PSWAP)&SWAPS.Buffer[i];
    if (s->Swap && s->Original) {
        InterlockedExchangePointer(s->Swap, s->Original);
        printf("reverted %wZ swap\n", &s->Name);
    }
}
 printf("-- unloaded\n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT driver, PUNICODE_STRING registry_path)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(registry_path);
  driver->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;
  ...
```

Уже не первый рах вижу как вот так используют функции:`driver->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;`
Как так можно,почему мы не указываем параметры в скобках?И как мы можем функцию типы void чему то присваивать?Что вообще происходит в этой строке?

P.s

```
typedef struct _DRIVER_OBJECT {
CSHORT Type;
CSHORT Size;
PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject;
ULONG Flags;
PVOID DriverStart;
ULONG DriverSize;
PVOID DriverSection;
PDRIVER_EXTENSION DriverExtension;
UNICODE_STRING DriverName;
PUNICODE_STRING HardwareDatabase;
PFAST_IO_DISPATCH FastIoDispatch;
PDRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverInit;
PDRIVER_STARTIO DriverStartIo;
PDRIVER_UNLOAD DriverUnload;
PDRIVER_DISPATCH MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION + 1];

} DRIVER_OBJECT;
typedef struct _DRIVER_OBJECT* PDRIVER_OBJECT;
```

Comment: У функции не тип `void`

Comment: Не знаете что такое указатель на функцию?..

Comment: Это просто указатель на функцию `function == &function` (т.е. можно без оператора взятия адреса).

Comment: И да, там не `void`, а `VOID`, т.е. это **typedef**.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь функция не вызывается. Она автоматически преобразуется к указателю на себя, и этот указатель записывается в переменную `driver->DriverUnload`.

Comment: а как можно,и зачем присваивать структуре указатель на функцию?...

Comment: @Whitehorse, в структуре есть поле с указателем на функцию с той же сигнатурой (и возвращаемым типом).

Comment: @Whitehorse, посмотрите как реализуется ООП в чистом Си =) Это называется `callback`

Comment: @Whitehorse Мы присваиваем не структуре, а ее полю с типом "указатель на функцию". Правда не знаю, при чем тут ООП.

Comment: HolyBlackCat только там указатель на структуру а не функцию же

Comment: @Whitehorse Там - это где? Определение `DriverUnload` в вопросе не показали.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: @Whitehorse `PDRIVER_UNLOAD DriverUnload;` Ну а что такое `PDRIVER_UNLOAD`? Его тоже надо найти.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ООП на чистом Си как раз реализуется через хранение *"методов"* в виде указателей на функцию, и передачей в эту функцию указателя на себя (т.е. на переменную структуры).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вроде того: `structvar.ptr2func(&structvar,others...);`

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Если под ООП имеете в виду полиморфизм, тогда да.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ООП - объектно-ориентированное программирование. Суть в том, что программист больше концентрируется на данных, а не алгоритме (очень грубо, но я думаю, что подробнее расписывать не нужно). Полиморфизм, наследование, инкапсуляция, абстракция -- не обязательные свойства ООП. Тут под ООП понимается стиль написания.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Ну так ведь чтобы "писать в стиле ООП", указатели на функции не нужны (не считая полиморфизма). От того, что вы заменили `foo(a, b, c)` на `a.foo(a, b, c)`, оно не становится "более ООП".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в C++ *"под капотом"* происходит примерно тоже самое. Указатель на структуру - это по сути this, через который функция и получит доступ к данным.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Если функция виртуальная, то она действительно вызывается через указатель на функцию. А если не виртуальная, то `a.foo(b, c)` - это синтаксический сахар для `foo(a, b, c)`, то есть указатели на функции не используются. Я про это.

Comment: Ну да, но в чистом Си нет полиморфизма, функции перегружать нельзя, и классов там нет, только структуры. А это своего рода и полиморфизм, и абстракция, и инкапсуляция. Только наследования не хватает =) Но на самом деле в чистом Си можно реализовать и наследование. Для этого достаточно сделать поля одной структуры подмножеством другой (они должны быть в таком же порядке и с такими же именами полей), и тогда возможен *"явыный upcasting"* =)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вот почему Торвальдс и многие другие считают C++ излишне усложнённым =) Чистый Си - это минимальный набор инструментов, из которых по желанию можно реализовать всё, что необходимо. Его гораздо проще держать в голове, ведь он по сравнению с Плюсами просто крошечный по объёму информации.

Comment: @megorit ключевые методы ООП на Си — `offsetof()` и `container_of()`. Поэтому структуры данных родителей просто встраивают в наследников. Ну и в Си 11 есть некое подобие templates.